# A redirect is not reloading the page correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am performing an update on some data, then trying to reload the current page I am on.

I have found the status code that allows me to change the redirect method from a put to a get (303). This functionality works, as when it finishes, I get the "finished loading get localhost:3000/". But the route I have predefined at "/" does not run.

The route "/" is supposed to grab some data, filter it by a boolean value, then pass it to the UI. This works when you hit the refresh button on the window. But the redirect does not work for some reason.

I have attached images for use.

This is the put route with the redirect I am having issues with.

```js
router.put('/api/update/:id', function(req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  Burger.update(id, function(results) {
    console.log(id);
    console.log(results);
  })
  res.redirect(303, '/');
})
```

Here is the "/" route that works appropriately when I hit the refresh button. but not when I use the redirected path above.

```js
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  Burger.all(function(data) {
    let eaten = [];
    let notEaten = [];
    // Looping through and depicting which burgers have been eaten and which ones have not.
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i].devoured === 0) {
        notEaten.push(data[i]);
      } else {
        eaten.push(data[i])
      }
    }
    // console.log(eaten);
    // console.log('============');
    // console.log(notEaten);
    var handleBarsObject = {
      eaten: eaten,
      notEaten: notEaten
    }
    // console.log(handleBarsObject);
    res.render('index', handleBarsObject);
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you're doing a `PUT` must mean that you're doing this via an Ajax call, not something typed into the URL bar.  Ajax calls by themselves do not show content in the browser.  They return content to your Javascript.

If you want to follow the redirect and show the redirected page content in the browser, then you will have to examine the response from the Ajax call in your Javascript, see that it's a 3xx status code, get the Location header from the response and then set `window.location` to the redirected URL to cause the browser to display the redirected page.

Comment: I am using the regular fetch() functionality from javascript. Would I be better off using a package like ajax or axios?

Comment: @ItsYaBoyFish - fetch is fine.  The point is that making an http request from your javascript does not change what is viewed in the browser unless you write your javascript to cause that.

Comment: I am fairly new to this area if you can't tell. So sorry if I am asking something dumb here. But when I examine the response coming back, I am not seeing the Location header. Do I need to specify that in the response on my server side?

Comment: @ItsYaBoyFish - A `res.redirect()` will set a `location` header.  A `res.render()` will just return a page of HTML.  You will have to use the fetch interface [`response.headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/headers) to see headers on the response.